# Update user account info is not working even after getting success message php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Hi I want the user that once logged in should be able to update their account information. When I fill out the for and I hit the submit button I get the success message, but when I check my database nothing has actually been updated.

I first started with this code

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    header("location: signin.php");
}


$name=$_SESSION['name'];
$submitted = '';

$sql = "SELECT `name`, `lastname`, `email`, `phone`, `address`, `apt`, `city`, `state`, `zip` FROM `Users` WHERE name = '$name'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$acc_name = $row['name'];
$acc_lastname = $row['lastname'];
$acc_email = $row['email'];
$acc_phone = $row['phone'];
$acc_address = $row['address'];
$acc_apt = $row['apt'];
$acc_city = $row['city'];
$acc_state = $row['state'];
$acc_zip = $row['zip'];

?>

<?php

 //UPDATE FORM
if(isset($_POST['save'])){ 

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$name);
    $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$lastname);
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$phone);
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$address);
    $apt=$_POST['apt'];
    $apt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$apt);
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$city);
    $state=$_POST['state'];
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$state);
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$zip);
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$updateQuery = "UPDATE Users SET name = '$name', lastname = '$lastname', email = '$email', phone = '$phone', address = '$address', apt = '$apt', city = '$city', state = '$state', zip = '$zip', password = '$hash' WHERE name = '$name'";
$updateResult = mysqli_query($con, $updateQuery);
if(!$updateResult){
die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');

}else{
$submitted = 'Your account has been updated.';
}
}
?>




 <div class="container">

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-2">
     </div>
       <div class="col-sm-8 form">
          <form id="updateForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
               <div class="controls">
                        <div class="text-center title">
                            <h1>Account Settings</h1>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="submitted">
                                <?php echo "<p> <font color=red size='5pt'>$submitted</font></p>"; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>


              <!--parents info -->


                        <div class="heading">

                            <h2 class="rowspace">Parent's Information</h2> 
                            <!--   <hr>-->
                        </div>


                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label for="form_name" class="question">First Name</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" data-error="First name is required." placeholder = "<?php echo $acc_name?>">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                  <div class="row form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        Last Name</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" data-error="Last name is required." placeholder = "<?php echo $acc_lastname?>">
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="email">Email Address</label></div>
                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" data-error="Valid email is required." placeholder = "<?php echo $acc_email?>">
                              <span></span>
                              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                          </div>
              </div>


                  <div class="row form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="form_phone">Phone Number</label>
                      </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" data-error="Phone number is required." placeholder = "<?php echo $acc_phone?>" >
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


              <!--ADDRESS-->

            <div class="heading container-fluid">
              <h2 class="rowspace">Address</h2> 
             <!-- <hr>-->
            </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="name">Address</label></div>
                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input id="address" type="text" name="address" class="form-control" data-error="Address is required." placeholder = "<?php echo $acc_address?>">
                              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                  <div class="row form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="name">APT Number</label></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <input id="apt" type="text" name="apt" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $acc_apt?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="name">City</label>
                        </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input id="city" type="text" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $acc_city?>">
                              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                  <div class="row form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="name">State</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <input id="state" type="text" name="state" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $acc_state?>">
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="name">Zip</label></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <input id="zip" type="text" name="zip" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $acc_zip?>">
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              <!-- LOGING INFO -->

            <div class="heading container-fluid">
              <h2>Login Information</h2> 
              <!--<hr>-->
            </div>


                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="name">New Password</label></div>
                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input id="password" type="text" name="password" class="form-control">
                              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                          </div>
                     </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="name">Confirm Password</label></div>
                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input id="confirmPw" type="text" name="confirmPW" class="form-control" >
                              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                          </div>
                     </div>






          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 text-center rowspace">
                    <input name="save" id="save" tabindex="5" value="Save Changes" type="submit" style="width:200px;">

              </div>
           </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

With this code above I kept getting `$submitted = 'Your account has been updated.'`

But it has not been updated in my database, I checked error log and there is no error showing.

Then I tried separating the code and putting the php into `edit_acc.php`

so my form tag action would then be: `action="edit_acc.php`

edit-acc.php :

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    $name=$_SESSION['name'];
    $submitted = '';
    }



    if(isset($_POST['save'])){ 

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$name);
    $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$lastname);
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$phone);
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$address);
    $apt=$_POST['apt'];
    $apt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$apt);
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$city);
    $state=$_POST['state'];
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$state);
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$zip);
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $updateQuery = "UPDATE Users SET name = '$name', lastname = '$lastname', email = '$email', phone = '$phone', address = '$address', apt = '$apt', city = '$city', state = '$state', zip = '$zip', password = '$hash' WHERE name = '$name'";
    $updateResult = mysqli_query($con, $updateQuery);
    if(!$updateResult){
    die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');

    }else{
    $submitted = 'Your account has been updated.';
    }
    }
    ?>
```

When I separated the code, after submitting edit_acc.php would show a blank page. Table still did not update and still nothing in the error log.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT**

I needed to change my query from:

`$updateQuery = "UPDATE Users SET name = '$name', lastname = '$lastname', email = '$email', phone = '$phone', address = '$address', apt = '$apt', city = '$city', state = '$state', zip = '$zip', password = '$hash' WHERE name = '$name'";`

to:

`$updateQuery = "UPDATE Users SET name = '$name', lastname = '$lastname', email = '$email', phone = '$phone', address = '$address', apt = '$apt', city = '$city', state = '$state', zip = '$zip', password = '$hash' WHERE id = '23'";`

Thank you to Asisito for recommending using id instead of name.

Comment: try to var_dump your $updateResult variable

Comment: When I did the var_dump($updateResult) in my edit_acc.php the entire page is white and printed "bool(true)" but it is still not updating in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see any part in your code where the mysqli database connection gets initialized, something like

```
$con = mysqli_connect("my_host","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

I suggest putting this code in the edit-acc.php after

```
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
$name=$_SESSION['name'];
$submitted = '';
}
```

because then you start to work with $con.

EDIT: I think it is better to work with unique IDs than with $name, because it is possible to have the same name multiple times. So you could store the Users ID in the Session, and get all of the data that you need at certain points on demand by the datbase.

Comment: I do have the database connection on both pages after session start. I didn’t include that piece of code in my question. I will update it. Though even with the database connected it does not work. I get that it was submitted but in my database there is no update.

Comment: Yes I realized that working with ids are better some time ago. I after getting everything to work I will go back and change it.

Comment: @Asisito thank you after changing my update query from `WHERE name = '$name'` to `WHERE id='23'` It started working. I guess the issue with using name was that I was also trying to update name. So I will most definitely go back and store id in my sessions instead.